# Why mutex is needed to set the fields of Logger struct?

Tags: go

In the below code from standard library:

```
type Logger struct {
    mu     sync.Mutex // ensures atomic writes; protects the following fields
    prefix string     // prefix on each line to identify the logger (but see Lmsgprefix)
    flag   int        // properties
    out    io.Writer  // destination for output
    buf    []byte     // for accumulating text to write
}
```

---

`mu` is used to set the fields of `Logger`. `mu` is also used to write the log(`l.out.Write(l.buf)`)

Why do we need mutex(`mu`) to set this fields of `Logger` struct? Is `mu` to enable multiple go-routines to perform atomic write?

Comment: From `go doc log.Logger`: "A Logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines;  it guarantees to serialize access to the Writer." Rule of  thumb: always consult the documentation first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As the comment for `mu sync.Mutex` reads that it ensures atomic writes and protects fields - `prefix`, `flag`, `out`, `buf`.

It allows methods/ functions - `SetFlags(int)`, `Prefix()`, `SetPrefix(string)`, `SetOutput(io.writer)`, `Flags`, `SetFlags(int)`, `Output(int, string)` to be used concurrently. The aforementioned reads/ writes from/ to the fields - `prefix`, `flag`, `out` and `buf` and uses mutex so that they are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutine(s).

Whether using a custom Logger created using `log.New(io.writer, string, int)` or using the global Logger, it's very much possible that same logger is used concurrently by multiple goroutine(s).